# Netbeans initComponents is bugging the code , how to solve?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm using the NetBeans IDE to develop a Swing application and in a JDialog window, I'm trying to use some components added by the netbeans and  also others added component dynamically, but when I try to add the component dinamic with the initComponents in the code it isn't showed.

The code:

```
 public RegrasUsuarioDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, "Preferências de conversão", modal);
    //initComponents();
    JRadioButton radioButton = new JRadioButton("Radio Button");

    optionsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    add(optionsPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

    optionsPanel.add(radioButton);



}
```

when I uncomment  the initComponents() method and comment the:

```
    optionsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    add(optionsPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
```

letting the Netbeans code create the base components it doesn't  works.

Comment: Is NetBeans using a `GroupLayout`?

Comment: Read up on and learn about the Java layout managers and how they work. This will help you learn how to add components to a container during runtime.

Comment: Yes, netbeans is using GroupLayout, I really think that's why I am not able to add new components, I will research how to add a component using layout manager. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reassign the optionsPanel variable because initComponents() is initializing it. If you want to initialize the panel yourself, select the panel in design view and in the Properties window select the "Code" tab, and put the same custom initialize code in the custom creation code area. See screenshot below:

[image: Properties screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

Get the container and then add your components to it and it will added to the form

```
Container layout = getContentPane();
layout.add(button1);
```